# regex for specific proxy

Tags: regex, proxy

How to choose only proxy from this

LIVE | 194.208.15.89:16698 | 1.65 | Vorarlberg | 6830 | 194-208-015-089.tele.net | Austria | Blacklist: Yes

I want to select only 194.208.15.89:16698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex : `\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}\b`

Explanation :

```
\b                  ->  Word boundary
[0-9]{1,3}          ->  Digit with length of 1 to 3
(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3} ->  Digit with length of 1 to 3 with a dot (.) at the end 3 times (Ex. 194.208.15.)
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/fjSCm5/3

For more accuracy you can use this : `\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):[0-9]{1,5}\b`

Comment: I would suggest using it this way `\b(?:[1-2]?[0-9]{1,2}\.){3}[1-2]?[0-9]{1,2}\b` to further enhance the ip matching accuracy, to cancel matching any ip that is above 300+ https://regex101.com/r/fjSCm5/2

Comment: thanks its work but how to choose proxy and port 194.208.15.89:16698 ?